# Java complex maps?

Tags: java, string, hashmap, boolean, maps

I´m sorry but I can´t think of other titles for my question. I´m writing a programm in Java, with a big amount of diffrent variables. So I decided to use HashMaps (or in generel maps). But I dont know that much about complex maps in Java. I only know "HashMaps" and how to use them. Here are 2 diffrent HashMaps which I thougth I can use :

```
public class Storage {
public static HashMap<String, Boolean> user = new HashMap<>();
public static HashMap<Integer, Double> money = new HashMap<>();
}
```

So, now it´s getting a bit confusing. So, as you can see, there are 2 HashMaps. In the first HashMap is the Value to every key true or false.

```
public class test {
String s = "Tester";
  public void on() {
  if(Storage.user(s) == true) {
  //That part will be my question
   }
 }
}
```

So, if the value of the given String is true, there should be an extra HashMap, like in the Storage class. But I mean, there should be to every String (if it´s true) a HashMap and they shouldnt share one Map. 
As I said, I dont know that much about maps and maybe HashMaps are completely false. If so, I´m sorry. 
Hopefully you get my problem and know a suitable solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a map of maps.

```
Map<String, Map<Integer,Double>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Then you can just put the value there for the String that is true.

Examples:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer,Double>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

The following:

```
Map.computeIfAbsent(Key, (a)->new HashMap<>()).put(i, d);
```

Behaves the same way as

```
Map<Integer,Double> innerMap = map.get(Key);
if (innerMap == null) {
     innerMap = new HashMap<>();
     map.put(Key, innerMap)
}
innerMap.put(i, d);
```

Assign some values

```
map.computeIfAbsent("A", (a)->new HashMap<>()).put(10,20.56);
map.computeIfAbsent("A", (a)->new HashMap<>()).put(20,4.2);
map.computeIfAbsent("A", (a)->new HashMap<>()).put(30,10.6);

map.computeIfAbsent("B", (a)->new HashMap<>()).put(1,2.);
map.computeIfAbsent("B", (a)->new HashMap<>()).put(2,2.44);
map.computeIfAbsent("B", (a)->new HashMap<>()).put(10,2.45);

map.computeIfAbsent("C", (a)->new HashMap<>()).put(30,3.2);
```

Print all the values

```
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

To get a specific Value

```
double d = map.get("A").get(10); // gets 20.56 from Map "A"
System.out.println(d);
```

If you already know the inner map is associated with a key you can just do the following:

```
// gets the map at "C"
// and puts 44.7 at key 44
map.get("C").put(44,44.7);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a separate `Map<Integer, Double>` for each user, as identified by a `String`, then create a `Map<String, Map<Integer, Double>>`.

You don't need a map to `Boolean`, because you can check for the existence of a user using [`containsKey()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-), or simply get the value of the outer map and check for `null`.

```
class Storage {
    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, Double>> user = new HashMap<>();
}
```

```
Map<Integer, Double> money = Storage.map.get(userName);
if (money != null) {
    // code here
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

When you are building the map, use the [`computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) and [`merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) methods, like this:

```
class Storage {
    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, Double>> user = new HashMap<>();

    public static void addUserMoney(String userName, int moneyKey, double amount) {
        user.computeIfAbsent(userName, k -> new HashMap<>())
            .merge(moneyKey, amount, Double::sum);
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
Storage.addUserMoney("John", 1, 9.95);
Storage.addUserMoney("Jane", 3, 3.75);
Storage.addUserMoney("John", 1, 4.25);
System.out.println(Storage.user);
```

*Output*

```
{John={1=14.2}, Jane={3=3.75}}
```

Comment: Thank you :). So, if there is a String, i want to use the put() method for giving my map an Integer and a Double-value. But how ? Because i want to give certain values / keys for this String.